# Nested routes in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9fMI.png)

How to navigate through the tabs in react.
Since I am currently in a tab, I have already used react route and the nested route does not work. how to make a transition through the masonry. Through a nested route or otherwise?

I have a react application inside this I have component with my routers

```js
export const Container = (props) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Redirect to={PERSONAL} />
      </Route>
      <Route path={PAGE} render={() => <PicturesMainPage />} />
      <Route path={PERSONAL} render={() => <PersonalPage />} />
      <Route path={PERSONAL_SETTINGS} render={() => <PersonalSettingsPage />} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

In this component I have  inside this component I drow an information about user with menu and i wand to drow athother components for click in to menu

```js
export const PersonalPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <PersonalInfo />
      <div className="personal-area__galery">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={PERSONAL}>
            <Redirect to={PERSONAL_GALLERY} />
          </Route>
          <Route path={PERSONAL_GALLERY} render={() => <Gallery images={images} />} />
          <Route path={PERSONAL_COLLECTIONS} render={() => <Collections />} />
          <Route path={PERSONAL_STATISTICS} render={() => <Statistics />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Person info

```js
let menu = [
  { href: PERSONAL_GALLERY, text: 'Галерея' },
  { href: PERSONAL_COLLECTIONS, text: 'Коллекции' },
  { href: '/personal/statistics', text: 'Статистика' },
];
let person = {
  profileName: 'Top Waifu',
  profileTag: '@topwaifu',
  profileDescription: 'Самая топовая вайфу твоего района',
  subscribers: '5.1m',
  subscriptions: 246,
};

export const PersonalInfo = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="personal-area__profile">
        <div className="personal-area__profile__description">
          <PersonalAvatar img={'assets/img/testImg4.png'} />
          <PersonalDescription
            profileName={person.profileName}
            profileTag={person.profileTag}
            profileDescription={person.profileDescription}
            subscribers={person.subscribers}
            subscriptions={person.subscriptions}
          />
          <div className="personal-area__profile__description__icons">
            <Share />
            <Settings />
            <MoreOptions />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="personal-area__menu">
        <ul>
          {menu.map((elem, i) => (
            <MenuElement key={i} menulink={elem.href} menuName={elem.text} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more code of these files. You can nest routes just as you have done here(atleast judging by the provided code), but with the information provided it is really difficult to determine the issue at hand.

Comment: I have added some info

Comment: What version of react-router-dom are you working with?

Comment: "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",

Comment: I don't see any over issues with the code, but it's a bit difficult to know for sure with the obfuscated paths. What exactly is the issue? Can you provide a *running* codesandbox that reproduces the issue for us to inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this codesandbox I made.

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cdn-1fn0u?file=/src/App.js

Here you can see a clear example of nesting routes.